# woocommerce support in wordpress theme not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a beginner in `wordpress` and I tried all the ways but I cannot make my theme `woocommerce` supportable. Below is my page.php

> page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="page">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post">
                    <h3 class="<?php post_class(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                            comments_template();
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

At first I duplicate `page.php` and create `woocommerce.php` and upload to server, but it fails, below is my `woocommerce.php`

> woocommerce.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 */
?>


<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="page">
            <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But it fails, after this I deleted `woocommerce.php` from server and edited my `functions.php` file to add woocommerce supportable code. Below is the code I added in my `functions.php` file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="page">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</div></div>';
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

but it also fails, you can see the output [here](http://www.enterhelix.com/shan/wordpress4.5/shop/)

If you see in debugger you can see that no woocommerce css file has been loaded.

Please help me with your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Check this link for integrate woocommerce in custom theme : https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: copy your woocommerce files in to theme directory and do and then create file woocomerce.php and paste the page.php code into woocommerce.php file

Comment: @hardiksolanki I checked, but still same

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Do I need to copy woocommerce folder in to my themes directory or some specific files..???

Comment: The specific file which one you edit . if it will not work then paste this code in your functions.php   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

Comment: I created a directory named 'woocommerce' under my themes directory and paste all file from ....wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates/ . And the code is already there in my functions.php

Comment: Only the **CSS** files of **woocommerce** are not loading, otherwise rest things are working ok, means the the **woocommerce.php** file is loading and when I click on image thumbnails of a particular product a popup open to display other pictures of the product....Only the **CSS** file of **woocommerce** is not loading, any suggestions please

Comment: Yes, I found it, it is **body_class()**. After I added <?php body_class(); ?> in the body tag it is working

Answer (score 3):

go to functions.php and add this at the top,

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```

most preferably at an initialisation function.